# GOINSECURE to enable http downlaods on packages from Github

Tags: go, go-get

I'm developing a CLI app at work in order to automate a couple tedious tasks, to do this I need to install a couple packages like [gotp](https://github.com/xlzd/gotp). I noticed that installing this new package into my project this error pops up.

```
go get github.com/xlzd/gotp
go: module github.com/xlzd/gotp: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/xlzd/gotp/@v/list": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I suppose this has something to do with my work PC's firewall or security configuration, since I was able to install a couple packages before the firewall was enabled on my PC. I read about the environment variable `GOINSECURE` which would enable `go get` to download packages over HTTP. So here's what I've done in my case.

```
export GOINSECURE="proxy.golang.org/*,github.com,github.com/*"
```

Still the same error pops up, am I missing something in my configuration?

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this error when I installed internal package, the solution is  selected proper proxy, I change my **GOPROXY** to internal proxy site address, and made **GOPRIVATE**, **GONOPROXY**, **GONOSUMDB** to null value.
In your case, you may attempt

```
GOINSECURE="proxy.golang.org/*,github.com,github.com/*"
GONOSUMDB="proxy.golang.org/*,github.com,github.com/*"
GOPRIVATE="proxy.golang.org/*,github.com,github.com/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this when trying to use go inside a bash shell in a ubuntu22 container running inside docker desktop for windows on a corporate network.

I want to do

```
go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig
```

But kept getting x509 errors

```
go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig
go: github.com/Masterminds/goutils@v1.1.1: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/%21masterminds/goutils/@v/v1.1.1.mod": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

1. `go get --insecure` is indeed deprecated and don't work any more
2. `export GOINSECURE=github.com` didn't work at first
3. it seemed to be more a combination of using `GOINSECURE` with

   `git config --global http.sslverify false`

One I'd set this sslVerify to false, it got further..

so I kept iterating the `go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig` and each time it got further.. calling out another url (probably a package dependency)

```
go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig
go: golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20211108221036-ceb1ce70b4fa: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto": https fetch: Get "https://golang.org/x/cr
ypto?go-get=1": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

each time I added the url to the GOINSECURE i.e.

```
export GOINSECURE=github.com,golang.org

go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig
go: sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.2.0: unrecognized import path "sigs.k8s.io/yaml": https fetch: Get "https://sigs.k8s.io/yaml?go-get=1": x509: certificate sig
ned by unknown authority

export GOINSECURE=github.com,golang.org,sigs.k8s.io
```

Until ultimately everything was downloaded

```
go get github.com/Masterminds/sprig
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/sprig v2.22.0+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/goutils v1.1.1
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/semver v1.5.0
go: downloading github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0
go: downloading github.com/huandu/xstrings v1.3.2
go: downloading github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.12
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/copystructure v1.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20211108221036-ceb1ce70b4fa
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/reflectwalk v1.0.2
""/bin/go build prehelm.go
go: downloading sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.2.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.3.0
```

I hope that helps, in short

1. ensure you have `git config --global http.sslverify false`
2. add the sites to you GOINSECURE= one by one until done.
3. Alternatively but less secure you can add `export GOINSECURE=*`